# Not getting ServerRedirectedEmbedUri for .txt, .png files Rest

Tags: document-library, file

When I execute the following rest endpoint, the field 'ServerRedirectedEmbedUri' is missing for files with .txt and .png extensions. For files with other extensions I get it.

Rest endpoint:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('${listName}')/items?$filter=(${itemtitle} eq ${item})
```

How can I get this Uri for all types of files. As I have to show file preview to users in the browser.

Comment: how about using `getpreview.ashx` ? You just need to create a url like `https://site-collection-url/_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx?path=https://site-collection-url/CustomList/abcd.png`. As far as i know, `ServerRedirectedEmbedUri` only works for Office documents

Comment: This only works for .png files. Not for .txt files.

Comment: Txt files are not available for preview, you can check [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2028380/unable-to-view-or-edit-office-files-by-using-office-online-or-office-w)